# How to select folder instead of file in FileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I try to get all filenames from folder which selected by user. I read msdn but found nothing. I need get filenames from folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not select folder or multiple files for single file upload control but you can use multiple file upload controls to do that.

You can find many custom controls helping you to do that, like, [Multiple file upload user control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24271/Multiple-File-Upload-User-Control).

Comment: Or let users create a ZIP file of that folder and have them upload the zip file.

Comment: @Adil, Please share a link or sample code for multiple file upload.

Comment: It means you have to use file control multiple times, any how you can find many custom controls helping you to do that, like, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24271/Multiple-File-Upload-User-Control

Answer (score 0):

You can't. HTML doesn't support what you are trying to do

If you to have multiple file upload, you would have to use a 3rd party component - usually written in Flash like `SWFUpload` or something like this: [Multiple File Upload With Progress Bar Using Flash](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15742/Multiple-File-Upload-With-Progress-Bar-Using-Flash)

Answer (score 0):

Try SlickUpload. It's free, and based on HTML5.

There should be no problem integrating this with an ASP.NET application.

http://slickupload.com/demos

Comment: SlickUpload allows you to select a folder on webkit-based browsers, doesn't work for IE or Firefox.  Specifically, it uses a webkit extension that is not supported in non-webkit browsers.  Refer to: http://html5test.com/compare/feature/files-fileSystem.html

Answer (score 0):

The file upload control only supports single file uploads. If you to have multiple file upload, you would have to use a 3rd party component - usually written in Flash.

Here an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

in your .aspx

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Upload Files" id="uploadBtn"/>
<div><%
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/uploads/"))
        For Each str As String In files
            Response.Write(Path.GetFileName(str) & "<br>")
        Next
%></div>
```

in your .vb

```
Imports System.IO

Protected Sub uploadBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles uploadBtn.Click
    Dim ImageFiles As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    For i As Integer = 0 To ImageFiles.Count - 1
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile = ImageFiles(i)

        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads/") & file.FileName)
    Next
End Sub
```